# Updating product stock status programmatically in Magento 2.3.x

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have been facing an issue lately, I want to allow some products to be added to cart and ordered (programmatically) even if they're `Out of Stock`, I have succeeded in updating both `is_in_stock` and `stock_status` but the product stock isn't updating right away, the changes only reflect when the page is reloaded.

This is the code I used to update and edit stock data

```
$product = $this->_productRepository->getById($childProduct->getId());

$product->setStockData([
           'stock_id' => 1,
           'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
           'manage_stock' => 0,
           'is_in_stock' => 1
          ]);

$product->setQuantityAndStockStatus([
           'stock_id' => 1,
           'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
           'manage_stock' => 0,
           'is_in_stock' => 1
          ]);

$product->setIsSuperMode(true);

$product->save();

die(var_dump($product->getIsSalable())); //Returns FALSE, however after refresh it returns TRUE.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: after your above code execute, can you try indexing programmatically and then check.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply and time, I tried that before with a `sleep(10)`, just to see if the reindexing is the problem! However that didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below sample code

```
$product->setStockData(['qty' => $yourQty, 'is_in_stock' => 1,'manage_stock'=>$your_manage_stock(Not Zero)]);
$product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => $yourQty, 'is_in_stock' => 1,'manage_stock'=>$your_manage_stock(Not Zero)]);
$product->save();
```

And you Get more information refer this link :-

**[How to update product qty and Stock Status update programmatically by product id : Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/289424/how-to-update-product-qty-and-stock-status-update-programmatically-by-product-id)**

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply and time. But have you read my post ? And the code I used ?

Comment: Please your add briefly and add full code .

Comment: Post is updated !

Comment: i am update my code check and try

Comment: Read my post again! My code works just fine

Comment: Hi @medjabir, I am facing the same issue. Have you resolved this issue? If so, could you please share the solution? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below solution:

```
$product->setStockData(
array(
    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
    'manage_stock' => 1,
    'is_in_stock' => 1,
    'qty' => 9
)
```

);

```
$product->save();
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply and time. It's the same code I used ! I don't think you understood what is the issue here.

Comment: Hello, you have set "manage_stock" to 0 and not specified the quantity which I have corrected in my code and works well for me.

Comment: Does your product got added to cart after changing the stock status programmatically ? My code also works, the problem is the update takes effect after page reload.