# The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again

Tags: magento2, product, stock

I'm running a custom import.

At some point the error: The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again.

Is triggered by : `$this->_productRepository->save($prod);`

Now I'm trying to figure out why.

```
MariaDB [magento]> select * from cataloginventory_stock;
+----------+------------+------------+
| stock_id | website_id | stock_name |
+----------+------------+------------+
|        1 |          0 | Default    |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

Is the fact I only have one stock there might be related? This script is launched by an URL from one of the front stores

```
MariaDB [magento]> select * from inventory_stock;
+----------+---------------+
| stock_id | name          |
+----------+---------------+
|        1 | Default Stock |
|        2 | Stock RE      |
|        3 | Stock YT      |
|        4 | Stock GF      |
|        5 | Stock MQ      |
|        6 | Stock BL      |
|        7 | Stock GP      |
|        8 | Stock SX      |
+----------+---------------+
```

I indeed have 8 websites (0 being an admin and 1 being base) website and stocks

EDIT : So I've been investigating a little bit more

It appears that my real error comes from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryRepository.php` on the get method

He can't find the category

```
        /** @var Category $category */
        $category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
        if (null !== $storeId) {
            $category->setStoreId($storeId);
        }
        $category->load($categoryId);
        if (!$category->getId()) {
            var_dump($storeId);
            var_dump($categoryId);
            var_dump($category->getCollection()->getSelect()->__toString());
            throw NoSuchEntityException::singleField('id', $categoryId);
        }
```

Store id : 10
Category Id : 50

Error : No such entity with id = 50

Problem is, the category actually exist; she is even found when I log the collection matching the request

```
SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id`, `main_table`.`level`, `main_table`.`path`, `main_table`.`position`, `main_table`.`is_active`, `main_table`.`is_anchor` FROM `catalog_category_flat_store_10` AS `main_table`
```

Among other results I have this one :

```
+-----------+-------+---------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| entity_id | level | path          | position | is_active | is_anchor |
+-----------+-------+---------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|        50 |     2 | 1/2/50        |        2 |         1 |         1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2+ version you can also update stocks using **CatalogInventory Module**...

```
$stockItem = $this->_stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($productSku);
// $stockItem->setQtyCorrection($QtyOrdered); 
//if you use setQtyCorrection($var) instead of manually set Exact Qty, then it will increase Stock Qty with Ordered Qty. 
$stockItem->setQty(100);
$stockItem->setIsInStock((bool)100);
$this->_stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($productSku, $stockItem);
```

for above method use, you have to include

> \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockStateInterface,
> \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,

For Full Example About Stock Update you can see [My Update Answer Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/317858/93504)
& Also you can see this full example at [my last question here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/345062/93504)

Even You can refer this Create **Helper Class Function** for [Stock Update See this Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/289428/93504), this helper function method also works, I tested it...

I used **Magento 2.4 Version** & its works for me...

I hope this one helps to you

Comment: If you found any issue for using above CatalogInventory module method , let me know

Comment: Hi, sorry but this doesn't seems to be stock related, he don't find the stock cause he don't find the category.